# S3 NoSuchKey error accessing yum repository for Apache Ambari 2.5.1

Tags: amazon-s3, centos, yum, ambari

I have built and installed Apache Ambari 2.5.1 in CentOS 6.9.  (By [Installation Guide for Ambari 2.5.1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.5.1)).

I opened the Ambari UI after started "ambari-server" and "ambari-agent". The default Apache Ambari 2.5.1 Public Repository is "http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/BUILDS/2.6.3.0-63" and "http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6".  I opened the browser and input the url, The browser showed that the specified key does not exist.  So I think that the Apache Ambari 2.5.1 Public Repository does not exist.

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.   </Message>
  <Key>HDP/centos6/2.x/BUILDS/2.6.3.0-63</Key>       
  <RequestId>81EA7B258C7ACDB4</RequestId>
  <HostId>
    3DEhVcTN7/LxCsa8doX8LNm1ltXGEvUI/5o4hOtKAooNU9iC58NeT8SwJPdE2ZbvXEGb4Hk7mIc=
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

Can you help me for figuring out this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are in fact valid yum repositories.  A yum repo can be served over HTTP.  Ambari is using an AWS S3 bucket as a convenient way to serve files over HTTP as a yum repo.

The reason you can't easily see anything in your browser when you navigate to the URL is that S3 does not truly maintain files in a directory hierarchy like a traditional web server providing static content.  Instead, it provides a mapping of keys to objects, and applications typically use a convention of a trailing `/` to simulate directories.

Even though the URL in your question doesn't serve meaningful content to a browser, we can use the [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to inspect the bucket.  (The following output is trimmed for brevity.)

```
> aws s3 ls s3://dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/BUILDS/2.6.3.0-63/
                           PRE RPM-GPG-KEY/
                           PRE accumulo/
                           PRE atlas/
                           ...
                           PRE hadoop/
                           ...
                           PRE hive/
                           PRE hive2/
                           ...
2017-07-17 18:03:01       2630 HDP-2.6.3.0-63.xml
2017-07-17 18:03:01      20366 artifacts.txt
2017-07-17 18:03:01        542 build.id
2017-07-17 18:03:01       8473 build_metadata.txt
2017-07-17 18:03:01        908 hdp-canary.repo
2017-07-17 18:03:01        602 hdp.repo
2017-07-17 18:03:01        578 hdp_private.repo
2017-07-17 18:03:01        574 hdp_public.repo
2017-07-17 18:03:01        612 hdpbn.repo
2017-07-17 18:03:09        497 hotfix_index.html
2017-07-17 18:03:06        502 index.html
2017-07-17 18:03:08        494 private_index.html
2017-07-17 18:03:07        493 public_index.html
```

We can see there are various sub-directories for components in the Apache Hadoop ecosystem.  We also can see the presence of an index.html file, so this URL works in browsers:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/BUILDS/2.6.3.0-63/index.html

We also see .repo files, which define this as a valid yum repo:

```
> curl http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/BUILDS/2.6.3.0-63/hdp.repo
#VERSION_NUMBER=2.6.3.0-63
[HDP-2.6.3.0]
name=HDP Version - HDP-2.6.3.0
baseurl=http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0/RPM-GPG-KEY/RPM-GPG-KEY-Jenkins
enabled=1
priority=1


[HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21]
name=HDP-UTILS Version - HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21
baseurl=http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0/RPM-GPG-KEY/RPM-GPG-KEY-Jenkins
enabled=1
priority=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you help me again? I have some issues in deploy.(upon)

Comment: @GuChao , glad to hear this answer helped!  I might be able to help with the deploy issue.  Possibly that would be a separate question.

Comment: To: [In deploy of Apache Ambari 2.5.1, Apache Metrics Collector install failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205352/in-deploy-of-apache-ambari-2-5-1-apache-metrics-collector-install-failed)