# Apache Metrics Collector install failed while deploying Apache Ambari 2.5.1

Tags: ambari

I've tried to deploy Apache Ambari 2.5.1, and Apache Metrics Collector install failed. I have researched this issue and I can not find the same issue in the Internet. Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

stderr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/AMBARI_METRICS/0.1.0/package/scripts/metrics_collector.py", line 86, in <module> AmsCollector().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 329, in execute method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/AMBARI_METRICS/0.1.0/package/scripts/metrics_collector.py", line 36, in install self.install_packages(env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 693, in install_packages retry_count=agent_stack_retry_count)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 155, in __init__ self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 54, in action_install self.install_package(package_name, self.resource.use_repos, self.resource.skip_repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/yumrpm.py", line 51, in install_package self.checked_call_with_retries(cmd, sudo=True, logoutput=self.get_logoutput())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 86, in checked_call_with_retries return self._call_with_retries(cmd, is_checked=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 98, in _call_with_retries code, out = func(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 72, in inner result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in checked_call tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep, timeout_kill_strategy=timeout_kill_strategy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 150, in _call_wrapper result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 303, in _call raise ExecutionFailed(err_msg, code, out, err)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install ambari-metrics-collector' returned 1. 
Error: Nothing to do
```

stdout:

```
2017-07-19 17:09:34,336 - Stack Feature Version Info: stack_version=2.6, version=None, current_cluster_version=None -> 2.6
2017-07-19 17:09:34,338 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf User Group mapping (user_group) is missing in the hostLevelParams
2017-07-19 17:09:34,341 - Group['livy'] {}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,343 - Group['spark'] {}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,343 - Group['hadoop'] {}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,344 - Group['users'] {}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,344 - User['hive'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,345 - User['livy'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,345 - User['zookeeper'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,346 - User['spark'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,347 - User['ams'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,348 - User['ambari-qa'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['users']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,348 - User['tez'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['users']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,349 - User['hdfs'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,350 - User['yarn'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,350 - User['hcat'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,351 - User['mapred'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,352 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,354 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa'] {'not_if': '(test $(id -u ambari-qa) -gt 1000) || (false)'}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,361 - Skipping Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa'] due to not_if
2017-07-19 17:09:34,362 - Group['hdfs'] {}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,363 - User['hdfs'] {'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop', 'hdfs']}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,363 - FS Type: 
2017-07-19 17:09:34,364 - Directory['/etc/hadoop'] {'mode': 0755}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,395 - File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hadoop-env.sh'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop'}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,396 - Directory['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/hadoop_java_io_tmpdir'] {'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 01777}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,421 - Initializing 2 repositories
2017-07-19 17:09:34,422 - Repository['HDP-2.6'] {'base_url': 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/BUILDS/2.6.3.0-63', 'action': ['create'], 'components': ['HDP', 'main'], 'repo_template': '[{{repo_id}}]\nname={{repo_id}}\n{% if mirror_list %}mirrorlist={{mirror_list}}{% else %}baseurl={{base_url}}{% endif %}\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0', 'repo_file_name': 'HDP', 'mirror_list': None}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,430 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP.repo'] {'content': '[HDP-2.6]\nname=HDP-2.6\nbaseurl=http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/BUILDS/2.6.3.0-63\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0'}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,432 - Repository['HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21'] {'base_url': 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6', 'action': ['create'], 'components': ['HDP-UTILS', 'main'], 'repo_template': '[{{repo_id}}]\nname={{repo_id}}\n{% if mirror_list %}mirrorlist={{mirror_list}}{% else %}baseurl={{base_url}}{% endif %}\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0', 'repo_file_name': 'HDP-UTILS', 'mirror_list': None}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,436 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP-UTILS.repo'] {'content': '[HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21]\nname=HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21\nbaseurl=http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0'}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,437 - Package['unzip'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,511 - Skipping installation of existing package unzip
2017-07-19 17:09:34,511 - Package['curl'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,519 - Skipping installation of existing package curl
2017-07-19 17:09:34,519 - Package['hdp-select'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,526 - Skipping installation of existing package hdp-select
2017-07-19 17:09:34,708 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf
2017-07-19 17:09:34,712 - checked_call['hostid'] {}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,729 - checked_call returned (0, 'a8c02132')
2017-07-19 17:09:34,733 - Package['ambari-metrics-collector'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2017-07-19 17:09:34,809 - Installing package ambari-metrics-collector ('/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install ambari-metrics-collector')
2017-07-19 17:09:37,830 - Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install ambari-metrics-collector' returned 1. Error: Nothing to do
2017-07-19 17:09:37,830 - Failed to install package ambari-metrics-collector. Executing '/usr/bin/yum clean metadata'
2017-07-19 17:09:38,131 - Retrying to install package ambari-metrics-collector after 30 seconds

Command failed after 1 tries
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your post to remove some unnecessary parts and make it more straight-forward, but there's still an important flow in it: you haven't provided commands that you used and hence your issue is hard to reproduce. Please do so for others to help you. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install ambari-metrics-collector' returned 1. 
Error: Nothing to do
```

Usually, this error means that some package is not available in repo, already installed and so on. Try running command manually in verbose mode like

```
/usr/bin/yum -y install ambari-metrics-collector
```

and post entire `yum` output.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the analysis part of Dmitriusan's answer and adding that the suggestion to run the yum manually may not work as the issue is about the package not being available in the repo. You may have to either add a repo that contains package in /etc/yum.repos.d/ and then retry or run the command in Dmitriusan's answer. Or manually download the rpm and install it as "rpm -i /path/to/package.rpm"